# bash: get one key-value pair out of array, or set to ""

Tags: arrays, bash

Given an associative array

```
declare -A kvs=( [k1]=v1 [k2]=v2 )
declare -A kvs=( ) # could be empty
```

what's the shortest way to extract *one* (arbitrary) key-value pair `$k $v`, or set `k='' v=''` if the array is empty? I came up with the following

```
k=( "${!kvs[@]}" )
: "${k:=}"
v=${kvs[${k:-none}]:-}
```

(which relies on the fact that, for subsequent code, `$k` will implicitly subscript to `${k[0]}`). But it seems it could be shorter. Note that bash doesn't allow subscripting with an empty string: `${kvs['']}` is an error. Not looking for string / eval hacks.

*Update*: the default assignment can be removed by adding an empty entry to the indexed array `$k`

```
k=( "${!kvs[@]}" '' ); v=${kvs[${k:-X}]:-}
```

The only real alternative (proposed by https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee right from the start and https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman in an answer) seems to be

```
k= v=; for k in "${!kvs[@]}"; do v=${kvs[$k]}; break; done
```

which, I agree, is less cryptic

Comment: How about simply `k=''; v=''` then attempt to loop over the array and `break`? It won't be shorter but way more understandable.

Comment: it serves as placeholder code for preparing a function to deal with multiple k-v's in subsequent commits -- so I kind of want a one-liner

Comment: `what's the shortest` Why do you need it to be short? Remove spaces around `( )` for 2 characters shorter. Replace `none` with `n` for 3 characters less. Are you really going for short? Remove `:-}` from `${kvs[...]:-}`, if the value is empty it's going to be empty anyway.

Comment: Just curious -- it feels I'm missing something. Plus it's placeholder code added to a function, I'd like a one-liner

Comment: The point was to see if there's something "semantically" shorter, not to save chars in sample code.

Comment: A lot of verbosity in defensively-written shell is to work around language design misfeatures. Thus, thinking "that's shorter, and it looks like it works, so it must be better!" is a quick route to corner-case bugs. So treating terseness as a virtue on its own is frowned on somewhat here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yes, my own sample code is "verbose" in that sense. But at this point I'm curious what language design *features* I can exploit. I think [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) doesn't allow restricting languages, so I asked here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the keys and break after the first iteration:

```sh
$ declare -A kvs=( [k1]=v1 [k2]=v2 )
$ k='' v=''
$ for k in "${!kvs[@]}"; do v=${kvs[$k]}; break; done
$ declare -p k v
declare -- k="k1"
declare -- v="v1"
```

and

```sh
$ declare -A kvs=()
$ k='' v=''
$ for k in "${!kvs[@]}"; do v=${kvs[$k]}; break; done
$ declare -p k v
declare -- k=""
declare -- v=""
```

It gets you an "arbitrary" key in the sense that associative array keys are unordered. However for the same bash version, it will get you the same key each time.

Comment: OK, this seems to be the only alternative. It's what @tripleee proposed right from the start, but let's have an accepted answer. I've added another tweak to my initial solution which (nicely I think) gets rid of the default assignment